# Coordinator layout hides my view

Tags: android, material-design, android-appbarlayout

I have a layout with a Floating Action Search View, which should be alway on top of my AppBarLayout. My search view is a sibling of the AppBarLayout as show you can see bellow:

[image]

```
  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorBackground"
        tools:context=".activity.DashboardActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content />
        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true" />
        <com.lapism.searchview.SearchView 
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:id="@+id/searchView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

When the AppbarLayout is full collapsed my view gets hide, I don't know why. The view can't be a child of the AppBarLayout because it's need to get the full height of the view in order to display the results.

Comment: Could you please share your FloatingSearchViewBehaviour?

Comment: @GuilhermeP Ops, I should have removed the Behaviour. My first though was that. The gif I uploaded is showing the error, without the behaviour.